# Is it possible to get coordinates for point from satellite image?

Tags: image, satellite

Is it possible to get coordination for point from satellite image using any programming language?  For example, if I clicked on a specific point on a satellite image hosted on a web application, I would like to retrieve Lon/Lat for that point.

Comment: please modify your question so that it is better to understand what exactly you want to do. Do you want to get the geographic coordinates of a specific point on a satellite image? What is the characteristic of the point?

Comment: for example, if I clicked on specific point on satellite image hosted on web application, I can retrieve Lon/Lat for that point

Comment: Do you have the server and access to the original format (e.g. GeoTIFF or NITF) image? Or are you asking for something like google maps or bing?

Comment: yes i have the GeoTIFF image